# Jenkins hanged when I try to build Unity project

Tags: android, windows, unity-game-engine, jenkins

I found Jenkins(windows) hanged when I try to build Unity project for android package.

I'm trying to use Jenkins with Unity plugin and windows bat to build project, after windows exe exported successful, android package exported failed.

The arguemnt when I use Unity plugin is

```
-batchmode -quit -projectPath "D:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\UnityJenkinsTest\workspace\QBAD" -executeMethod QBADBuildScript.Android -logFile "${WORKSPACE}/Build-Log.txt"
```

Meanwhile, I try using a windows bat to execute the same command from Jenkins, the result is the same.

```
"D:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe" -batchmode -quit -projectPath "D:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\UnityJenkinsTest\workspace\QBAD" -executeMethod QBADBuildScript.Android -logFile "${WORKSPACE}/Build-Log.txt"
```

When the building process went to the some part of build process, it hanged, and the build of jenkins never ended. I check with succeed log, it hanged before entering the part of Android.

```
(succeed log)
Used Assets, sorted by uncompressed size:
....
AndroidSDKTools: // This line and below never showed when hanging happened.
root          : D:/Android/sdk
tools         : D:/Android/sdk\tools
platform-tools: D:/Android/sdk\platform-tools
build-tools   : D:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1
```

On the contrary, when I call the same script from command console of windows, it ended and succeed. I wonder what went wrong. Maybe I need set up environment variable for Jenkins.

The version of my Jenkins is 1.614, the version of my Unity is 5.0.1 .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static class AndroidSDKFolder
 {
     public static string Path
     {
         get { return EditorPrefs.GetString("AndroidSdkRoot"); }
         set { EditorPrefs.SetString("AndroidSdkRoot", value); }
     }
 }
```

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/495735/setting-android-sdk-path-in-environment-variable.html <-- This should help, setting the android sdk path stops the hang.

Comment: Wonderful!!! It works, I set the android sdk folder path before I call BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(). Thanks a lot, @Knoxx .